# Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259 with a group by and count

Tags: sql-server

Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.  When I remove the count and group by the query works perfectly.  I add the count and group by I get the error above.

```
'''
DECLARE @sub VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @qry VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(250);
DECLARE @query_ath NVARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @query_attachment_filename NVARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @tab char(1) = CHAR(9);


SELECT @sub = 'Daily Absence Report';
SELECT @msg = 'Please refer to the attached spread sheet for the report.'

SELECT @query_ath = 'select a.SCS_STUDENT,
                            concat(d.FIRST_NAME,'' '',d.LAST_NAME) as Student_Name,
                            c.STA_OTHER_COHORT_GROUPS,
                            b.STC_COURSE_NAME,
                            b.STUDENT_ACAD_CRED_ID,
                            e.SCS_ABSENT_DATES,
                            count(case e.SCS_ATTENDANCE_TYPES when ''A'' then 1 end) as 
                            Number_of_Absences
                       from STUDENT_COURSE_SEC a, STUDENT_ACAD_CRED b, STA_OTHER_COHORTS c, PERSON 
                            d, SCS_ATTENDANCE e
                      where a.SCS_STUDENT_ACAD_CRED = b.STUDENT_ACAD_CRED_ID
                        and b.STC_REPORTING_TERM = ''2019FA''
                        and b.STC_PERSON_ID = left(c.STUDENT_ACAD_LEVELS_ID, 7)
                        and b.STC_PERSON_ID = d.ID
                        and c.STA_OTHER_COHORT_GROUPS like ''AT%''
                        and c.STA_OTHER_COHORT_GROUPS <> ''ATCHR''
                        and a.STUDENT_COURSE_SEC_ID = e.STUDENT_COURSE_SEC_ID
                        and e.SCS_ATTENDANCE_TYPES = ''A''
                        and CONVERT(date, getdate()) = e.SCS_ABSENT_DATES
                      group by a.SCS_STUDENT,
                               concat(d.FIRST_NAME,'' '',d.LAST_NAME),
                               c.STA_OTHER_COHORT_GROUPS,
                               b.STC_COURSE_NAME,
                               b.STUDENT_ACAD_CRED_ID,
                               e.SCS_ABSENT_DATES';



   SELECT @query_attachment_filename = 'ath_absences.csv';

          EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @profile_name = 'elearning no shows',
          @recipients = 'email', --'ajenkins@eastms.edu',
          @copy_recipients = 'rboles@eastms.edu',
          @body = @msg,
          @subject = @sub,
          @execute_query_database = 'db_server',
          @query = @query_ath,
          @query_attachment_filename = 'ath_absences.csv', 
          @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
          @query_result_header = 1,
          @query_result_width = 256,
          @query_result_separator=@tab,
          @query_result_no_padding = 1;
    '''
```

Comment: `case when e.SCS_ATTENDANCE_TYPES = ''A'' then 1 else 0 end` perhaps? The SQL needs to be valid before SQLCMD can execute it.

Comment: The sql works outside of the of EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

Comment: Hmm I suppose so, I don't see it written in that syntax ever. Have you tried running it directly against sqlcmd?

Comment: haven't tried that yet

Comment: I am not sure how many whitespace characters you have before each line. Maybe you need to increase @query_ath to more than 1000. Maybe it's less than 1000 removing GROUP BY and COUNT and more if you add.

Comment: or maybe take out the end of line characters at `as Number_of_Absences`?

Comment: Dávid Laczkó  that worked thanks for your help.

Comment: OK, I provided it as an answer, so you can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our discussion in the comments, please increase the number of characters for @query_ath.